# Chosen-select multi-select - disable 2nd select based on selected.count of first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 "chosen" multi-select boxes.

`Group -> Class -> Category -> Subcategory`

When an option is selected from `Group`, it will populate `Class` with the relevant options (via ajax/json).

This is working great. However, I need to extend this to the following:

If `0`, or more than `1` options are selected from group, I need to disable the remaining 3 sub-selects.

Just as if I were to select 0 or more than 1 options from `Class`, I would need to disable, `category` and `subcategory`.

The trouble I am having is, how do I get js to know how many options have been selected? As you can see in the image of the console below. I have first selected `Confectionery`, and then `Liquor`. The first `console.log` is `this.value` (of group) and the 2nd is the ajax response with my options for the class field. And when I go to add liquor, it says that confectionery is still this.value, I was expecting an `array` of `{Confectionery, Liquor}` which is why i have asked the question.

Here is my javascript:

each of my select boxes call this function `onChange` `menuChange('NEXT-FIELD', this.value)`

```
function menuChange(field, value){

    /* clear all child select box values */
    switch(field){

        case "period":

            if(value == "year"){

                $("#yr").show();
                $("#yrmth").hide();

            } else if(value == "month"){

                $("#yr").show();
                $("#yrmth").show();

            } else if(value == "ytd"){

                $("#yr").hide();
                $("#yrmth").hide();

            } else if(value == "ttm"){

                $("#yr").hide();
                $("#yrmth").hide();

            }


        break;


    }
    console.log(value);
    document.getElementById(field).options.length = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxrequest.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { field: field,
              value: value },
        success: function (response) {


            $.each(response,function(key, value)
                {
                    $("#" + field).append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                });

            if(field == "period"){

            } else {
                $('#' + field).trigger("chosen:updated");
            }


           console.log(response);


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });



}

$(document).ready(function(){
  //Start with all subs disabled.
  $('select:gt(5)').attr('disabled','disabled');
  arrSelects = ['group','class','category','subcategory'];

  //Listen to all selects for change
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    doSelects($(this));
  });
})

function doSelects(sel) {
  var selIndex = arrSelects.indexOf(sel.attr('class'));
  var selCount = sel.val().length;

  if(selCount == 1) {
    $('select:eq(' + parseInt(selIndex + 1) + ')').removeAttr('disabled');
    return;
  }

  if(!selCount || selCount > 1) {
    $('select:gt(' + parseInt(selIndex) + ')').attr('disabled','disabled').find('option').removeAttr('selected');
    return;
  }
}
```

[image: console]

EDIT:  Here is the output HTML of my page. I have also update the javascript above to include the full function, so that the 'period' parts of my page make more sense.

```
<body class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions">
    <form style="margin:0; padding:0;" action="changedb.php" method="post">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="dashboard.php">Title</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select style="display: inline; margin-top: 10px;" class="input-sm" name="dbname">
                        <option value="2_sar" selected="">SAR</option>
                        <option value="2_lstr">LSTR</option>
                    </select>
                    <button style="display: inline;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>        
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="?report=salesanalysis">Sales Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=baa">Brand Affinity Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=bvb">Brand Affinity by Nationality</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=xcatr">Cross Category Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=nationality">Nationality Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=destination">Destination Report</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="?report=changepw">Change My Password</a></li>
                                <li><a href="cp/index.php">Control Panel</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="?report=salesanalysis">Sales Analysis <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=baa">Brand Affinity Analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=bvb">Brand Affinity by Nationality</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=xcatr">Cross Category Analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=nationality">Nationality Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=destination">Destination Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Main Content Div -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-2" align="center">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div align="left" class="col-xs-3">
                            <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sales Analysis</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div align="left" class="col-xs-7 col-offset-xs-3">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Analyse &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="measure" class="input-sm">
                                                <option value="sales">Sales</option>
                                                <option value="units">Units</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Period &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select onchange="menuChange('period', this.value)" name="period" class="input-sm">
                                                <option value="year">Year</option>
                                                <option value="month">Month</option>
                                                <option value="ytd">YTD</option>
                                                <option value="ttm">TTM</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select style="width: 80px" class="input-sm" onchange="menuChange('yrmth', this.value)" name="yr" id="yr">
                                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select style="width: 80px" class="input-sm" name="yrmth" id="yrmth" hidden="">
                                                <option value="201501">Jan</option>
                                                <option value="201502">Feb</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                            Filters &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <select data-placeholder="Group" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="menuChange('class', this.value)" name="group[]" id="group">
                                <option value="Confectionery">Confectionery</option>
                                <option value="Liquor">Liquor</option>
                                <option value="Tobacco">Tobacco</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="group_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Group" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 65px;"></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<select data-placeholder="Class" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="menuChange('category', this.value)" name="class[]" id="class"></select>
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="class_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Class" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px;"></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<select data-placeholder="Category" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="menuChange('subcategory', this.value)" name="category[]" id="category" disabled="disabled"></select>
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-disabled" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="category_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Category" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 83px;" disabled=""></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<select data-placeholder="Subcategory" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" name="subcategory[]" id="subcategory" disabled="disabled"></select>
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-disabled" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="subcategory_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Subcategory" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 105px;" disabled=""></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Go!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('.chosen-select').chosen();
          $('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
          });
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
</body>
```

This is the error in console when i try to remove an option.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is with your code. It's working correctly:

```
<body class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions">
    <form style="margin:0; padding:0;" action="changedb.php" method="post">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="dashboard.php">Title</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <select style="display: inline; margin-top: 10px;" class="input-sm" name="dbname">
                        <option value="2_sar" selected="">SAR</option>
                        <option value="2_lstr">LSTR</option>
                    </select>
                    <button style="display: inline;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>        
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="?report=salesanalysis">Sales Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=baa">Brand Affinity Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=bvb">Brand Affinity by Nationality</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=xcatr">Cross Category Analysis</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=nationality">Nationality Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?report=destination">Destination Report</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="?report=changepw">Change My Password</a></li>
                                <li><a href="cp/index.php">Control Panel</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="?report=salesanalysis">Sales Analysis <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=baa">Brand Affinity Analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=bvb">Brand Affinity by Nationality</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=xcatr">Cross Category Analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=nationality">Nationality Report</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?report=destination">Destination Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Main Content Div -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-2" align="center">
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div align="left" class="col-xs-3">
                            <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sales Analysis</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div align="left" class="col-xs-7 col-offset-xs-3">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Analyse &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="measure" class="input-sm">
                                                <option value="sales">Sales</option>
                                                <option value="units">Units</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Period &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select onchange="menuChange('period', this.value)" name="period" class="input-sm">
                                                <option value="year">Year</option>
                                                <option value="month">Month</option>
                                                <option value="ytd">YTD</option>
                                                <option value="ttm">TTM</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select style="width: 80px" class="input-sm" onchange="menuChange('yrmth', this.value)" name="yr" id="yr">
                                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select style="width: 80px" class="input-sm" name="yrmth" id="yrmth" hidden="">
                                                <option value="201501">Jan</option>
                                                <option value="201502">Feb</option>
                                            </select>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="selectGroup" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
                            Filters &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <!-- <select data-placeholder="Group" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="menuChange('class', this.value)" name="group[]" id="group">
                                <option value="Confectionery">Confectionery</option>
                                <option value="Liquor">Liquor</option>
                                <option value="Tobacco">Tobacco</option>
                            </select> -->
                            <select multiple class="group">
                              <option value="Confectionery">Confectionery</option>
                              <option value="Liquor">Liquor</option>
                              <option value="Tobacco">Tobacco</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="group_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Group" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 65px;"></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;<select data-placeholder="Class" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="menuChange('category', this.value)" name="class[]" id="class"></select> -->
                            <select multiple class="class">
                              <option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="class_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Class" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 60px;"></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;<select data-placeholder="Category" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" onchange="menuChange('subcategory', this.value)" name="category[]" id="category" disabled="disabled"></select> -->
                            <select multiple class="category">
                              <option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option>
                            </select>                            
                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-disabled" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="category_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Category" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 83px;" disabled=""></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;<select data-placeholder="Subcategory" style="width: 115px; display: none;" class="chosen-select" multiple="" name="subcategory[]" id="subcategory" disabled="disabled"></select> -->
                            <select multiple class="subcategory">
                              <option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option>
                            </select>   
                            </div>div>                         

                            <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-disabled" style="width: 115px;" title="" id="subcategory_chosen">
                                <ul class="chosen-choices">
                                    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Subcategory" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 105px;" disabled=""></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="chosen-drop">
                                    <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Go!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('.chosen-select').chosen();
          $('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
          });
    </script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Start with all subs disabled.
  $('#selectGroup select:gt(0)').attr('disabled','disabled');
  arrSelects = ['group','class','category','subcategory'];

  //Listen to all selects for change
  $('#selectGroup select').on('change',function(){
    doSelects($(this));
  });
})

function doSelects(sel) {
  var selIndex = arrSelects.indexOf(sel.attr('class'));
  var selCount = sel.val() == null?0:sel.val().length;

  if(selCount == 1) {
    $('#selectGroup select:eq(' + parseInt(selIndex + 1) + ')').removeAttr('disabled');
    return;
  }

  if(!selCount || selCount > 1) {
    $('#selectGroup select:gt(' + parseInt(selIndex) + ')').attr('disabled','disabled').find('option').removeAttr('selected');
    return;
  }
}
</script>


    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
</body>
```

Comment: It's still not enabling the class field when I select a value from group. It's still updating the values correctly, just not enabling the box.  I've also tried adding: `$('#selectGroup select:eq(' + parseInt(selIndex + 1) + ')').trigger("chosen:updated");`  and this still hasn't enabled it.   I've tried this with and without the 'chosen' plugin enabled too. I do appreciate your help here.

Comment: Try adding some console dumps inside of the event listener and the function to see if it's even triggering.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted your answer because it does in fact work with regards to the question title, and for future readers. It's clear that it's somethings get elsewhere in my page that's causing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Start with all subs disabled.
  $('select:gt(0)').attr('disabled','disabled');
  arrSelects = ['group','class','category','subcategory'];

  //Listen to all selects for change
  $('select').on('change',function(){
    doSelects($(this));
  });
})

function doSelects(sel) {
  var selIndex = arrSelects.indexOf(sel.attr('class'));
  var selCount = sel.val().length;

  if(selCount == 1) {
    $('select:eq(' + parseInt(selIndex + 1) + ')').removeAttr('disabled');
    return;
  }

  if(!selCount || selCount > 1) {
    $('select:gt(' + parseInt(selIndex) + ')').attr('disabled','disabled').find('option').removeAttr('selected');
    return;
  }
}
</script>

<body>
group:<select multiple class="group"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
class:<select multiple class="class"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
category:<select multiple class="category"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
subcategory:<select multiple class="subcategory"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT-------

Try this in case there are other selects on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Start with all subs disabled.
  $('#selectGroup select:gt(0)').attr('disabled','disabled');
  arrSelects = ['group','class','category','subcategory'];

  //Listen to all selects for change
  $('#selectGroup select').on('change',function(){
    doSelects($(this));
  });
})

function doSelects(sel) {
  var selIndex = arrSelects.indexOf(sel.attr('class'));
  var selCount = sel.val().length;

  if(selCount == 1) {
    $('#selectGroup select:eq(' + parseInt(selIndex + 1) + ')').removeAttr('disabled');
    return;
  }

  if(!selCount || selCount > 1) {
    $('#selectGroup select:gt(' + parseInt(selIndex) + ')').attr('disabled','disabled').find('option').removeAttr('selected');
    return;
  }
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="selectGroup">
group:<select multiple class="group"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
class:<select multiple class="class"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
category:<select multiple class="category"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
subcategory:<select multiple class="subcategory"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option><option value="4">Option 4</option></select><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's a neat bit of code.  One thing though, is that This work 100% on a page on its own, however when I paste the JS straight into my file, the first `group` box is disabled too onready

Comment: Adam, if there are any other selects, they will change the index. What other code is on the page? Added new code to the original answer to handle a page that has OTHER selects in it.

Comment: There are 5 other selects beforehand.  I have tried both scripts. (including wrapping a div around the selects for script2).  I now cannot remove an option from the selection, and it doesn't enable the next select in the line

Comment: I have posted the output HTML as is from F12 in chrome.  Be mindful that the exact tags in the body might not be correct because i've removed a large section of SVG stuff, and the html is generated in php, so would have been far messier. It uses bootstrap too, just incase you wondered what was in the head.

Comment: Strangely, when I click out of the select ive been adding options to, it all adds the placeholder to the end of the 'selected' list.